# Lie Theory in Finite Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups

Currently, I have interest in Finite groups. I also want to learn Lie Groups, Lie algebras, and their representations. But I do not have any motivation for it.

**Question** What are simple but interesting applications of Lie theory in finite groups?

(I know that the famous Fiet-Thomson theorem, and classification of finite simple groups have used Lie theory too; but its hard to understand in a shot.)

Comment: There are many, many motivations to study Lie theory: it's important in geometry, mathematical physics, algebraic topology, algebraic geometry, number theory...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but might help motivate you: in many situations, Lie groups and particularly *compact* Lie groups are the natural generalizations of finite groups, and the typical next step after we've understood the behavior of finite groups in these situations is to repeat the program for Lie groups.  For example, vanilla real/complex representation theory has finite groups acting on finite-dimensional vector spaces; since these vector spaces are in particular manifolds, it makes sense to ask analogous questions about smooth representations of Lie groups.

Comment: Moreover, many nice finite groups arise as matrix groups over finite fields.  One could view the real and complex matrix groups as topological, characteristic-zero versions of these.  I couldn't comment as to whether the theory of one of these sorts of objects applies to the theory of the other, but I'd be surprised if no deep connection existed.

Comment: The [McKay conjecture](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/McKay_conjecture) is still open for groups of lie type.

Comment: Probably not the answer you were looking for, but I can't resist pointing out that a finite group is a compact discrete Lie group of dimension $0$.